# How can I share data between successive builds of a Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins pipeline includes an Integration Stage where I deploy my software and test it in combination with a real-life instance of resource X. To use X, I must subscribe to it before I start the test, and unsubscribe from it afterwards. Each of these steps can take up to several minutes.

In daily operation, I keep observing the pattern that a first build #42 unsubscribes from X. Seconds later, the next build #43 starts and wants to subscribe to X. X, still captured in the previous unsubscription, does not handle this well and breaks, consequently also breaking the build #43.

The pattern we're doing there - unsubscribing and resubscribing in quick succession - is not something to be expected in real life and I cannot really pretend X was doing something wrong there. So instead of urging X's team to change the resource, I'd prefer to improve my test.

The first idea that came into my mind was creating a new instance of X each time. This proved to be too complicated. It doesn't have the APIs for that, technical users are too hard to obtain, and instantiation is so heavy it would slow down the already-slow pipeline down by several minutes more. I discarded the possibility.

Another idea that came into my mind was creating multiple instances N of X. Successive builds would then be able to choose a different one each time, giving the other instances sufficient time to cool down before they are used again.

A trivial solution would be to create the pool of instances and then randomly choose one of them. This would leave me with a 1/N chance of choosing the same one as the build before. With high N, this can be moved into an acceptable range of failure probability, but it still leaves this nagging "it's not really reliable" feeling you don't want to have with your pipeline.

A more complex solution would be that I saved in some central place when each instance of X was used for the last time, i.e. a simple map of instance number to last-used timestamp. However, for that, I'd need to exchange information between the builds. Leading up to my question:

How can I share a small amount of data between builds of the same job? Preferrably a simple variable that can be accessed by the pipeline code right away. Alternativey, a file or some other means of permanent storage. The solution should survive the fact that some builds might break before they ever reach that stage, i.e. should not imply that the direct predecessor passed that stage successfully.

Comment: Did you try by creating your own Global Environment variable? The environment variable would retain the value after each build.

Comment: Interesting idea. Didn't come into my mind. Let me give it a spin.

Comment: @SiddharthKaul Tried it out. It works. Also like the idea. A pretty simple solution for my situation. Turn it into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Global Environment Variable.

The global environment variable will retain the value after each build.

You can use the same environment variables across jobs or across the successive build of the same job.